# python how to structure this class

Tags: python, class, oop

Im having some trouble deciding the best way to structure a certain class. The class will take in some strings as settings and the methods will create different kinds of charts based on the settings....

for example. It could be called like this...

```
c = ChartEngine(type='line', labels='foo bar', data='1, 2', data2='3, 4')
chart = c.make_chart()
```

IDK if it is best to structure this as a class, or just a function that will call other functions in the same module...IDK if I should just put logic in the `__init__` function that will setup to call the `make_chart` function or if there is some other way.

```
def __init__(*settings*):
    self.type = type
    self.labels = labels
    self.data = data
    ....

make_chart(self.type, self.labels, self.data):
    if self.type == "line":
        line_chart(settings)
    elif self.type == "bar":
        bar_chart(settings)
    ...
```

How would you structure a class like this?

Comment: You can better call `make_chart(type)` rather than explicitly checking and passing the same value.

Comment: For one, I'd use `==` instead of `=` in the if/elif tests. Also, this is a bit too broad - it will probably end up being closed because it's mostly opinion-based.

Comment: Yea,it depends on your own habit. As for me, I would like to save settings in `__init__` and call `make_chart` explicitly by reading settings which have already been saved.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal, good point, you are correct. I am still left with the problem of what to do inside the `make_chart` function though. I would still have to call the `line_chart` method by a string of `if` `elif` which seems like it can be done better...

Comment: @Acepcs, see my comment above. Thanks for your input I will rephrase my main question

Comment: You might wanna use inheritance

Comment: @Eddie, how would inheritance help in this situation?

Comment: @deltaskelta, Well you should consider splitting your class, since less is more, you'd better divide different parts into different small classes. Or at least, divide them into different functions inside a big class. Try not to use one single function `make_chart` and not to write some logic in it to call different functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design problem. By nature of the problem, you could use many subjective approaches. You'd optimally like to design your program in such a way that your source is generally de-coupled, leading to future changes being trivial. However *over-engineering* is a thing, so take into account the requirements at hand. Various approaches could yield certain benefits. Here is an example approach below.

You could have a master control class called `ChartEngine` (*as you've mentioned*) that can dispatch the various charts via `Chart` sub-classes. You could then implement a base class called `Chart` that serves as the super class to the various variations. The nature of your program suits inheritance more than composition in my opinion (*again, many different approaches can be used*).

```
class Chart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def draw(self):
        pass
    ...
```

Then extend/override the base class' functionality via the inheritance of `Chart`. You could then implement something like a `Line` class for example:

```
class Line(Chart):
    pass

class Bar(Chart):
    pass
```

As for `ChartEngine`, you could could have the class have dispatch methods for each of the various graph types similar to routes in a MVC web app. One approach could be to have a dictionary that keeps track of the various graphs and their associated dispatch methods.

```
class ChartEngine(object):
    type_to_dispatch = {"bar" : dispatch_bar, "line" : dispatch_line}
    def __init__(self, type, labels, data):
        self.type = type
        self.labels = labels
        self.data = data
        ...

    def make_chart(self):
        type_to_dispatch[self.type]()
    def dispatch_line(self):
        pass
    def dispatch_bar(self):
        pass
```

Comment: I like this idea. It looks like inside the `dispatch` methods, the chart-type (`Chart` subclasses) will be instnatiated, correct?

Comment: That's the idea. I left those incomplete since there's a vast way you could go about that. You could even make a `Dispatch` class that defines how to dispatch a graph so you could avoid any duplicated code. Or you can just call your constructors right there. Lots of options.

Answer (score 3):

Use tests as a design tool. Write a test for one trivial minimal feature you want. Let it fail, then write the minimal code required to make it pass.  Then write a other test with an other feature, let it fail and so on. Using this development cycle ([TDD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)), you design from the user point of view and enforce proper encapsulation and abstraction of your implementation. You may want to learn about the [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) module.

At first sight I'd say that your class as you plan it will know too much about too many different things.  Read about SRP and other SOLID principles to get you started on the matter. Most importantly, implement only what you need now, nothing more.

Finaly, `ChartEngine` looks like a use case for the abstract factory pattern which can be hard to implement with elegant code.  Start with the most simple use cases and refactor early.

Comment: That is a very good idea actually as it helps to evolve the Chart Engine naturally and organically without having to spend time designing a perfect solution upfront. Object Orienting in a Java way might not be the best solution as Python already has a lot of factory patters built into the language itself, supports multiple inheritance with MROs and Operator Overloading etc.